# Java Crashing when trying to draw graphics in OSX Maverics

Tags: java, macos, game-engine, graphics2d

I am following a Java game development tutorial and although this seems to work on windows java crashes on my Macbook Pro with the following error:

C [libGL Image.dylib+0x24221] storeColor+0x5d1

Currently the project is set in eclipse and has the following classes:

Game:

```
package Main;
/**
 * Created by beuden on 1/3/14.
 */

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {

         JFrame window = new JFrame("Dragon Tale");
         window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         window.setContentPane(new GamePanel());
         window.setResizable(false);
         window.pack();
         window.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

GamePanel:

```
package Main;

import GameState.GameStateManager;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * Created by beuden on 1/3/14.
 */
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener{

// Dimensions
public static final int WIDTH = 320;
public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
public static final int SCALE = 2;
Dimension d = new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);

// game Thread
private Thread thread;
private boolean running;
private int FPS = 60;
private long targetTime = 1000 / FPS;

//image
private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g;

// game state manager
private GameStateManager gsm;

public GamePanel()
{
    super();
    setPreferredSize(d);
    setMaximumSize(d);
    setMinimumSize(d);


    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

public void addNotify()
{
    super.addNotify();
    if(thread == null)
    {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        addKeyListener(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}

public void init()
{
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    running = true;

    gsm = new GameStateManager();



}

public void run()
{
    init();

    long start,elapsed,wait;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double nsPerTick = 1000000000/60D;

    int frames = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double delta = 0; // Now many unprocessed nanoseconds have gone by so far.

    // Game Loop
    while(running)
    {


        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
        lastTime = now;
        boolean shouldRender = false;

        while(delta >=1)
        {
            ticks++;
            update();
            delta -=1;
            shouldRender = true;
        }
        if(shouldRender)
        {
            frames++;
            draw();
            drawToScreen();
        }

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer > 1000)
        {
            lastTimer += 1000;
            System.out.println("Frames: " + frames + "," + "Ticks: " + ticks);
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }

    }
}

public void update()
{
    gsm.update();
}

public void draw()
{
   gsm.draw(g);
}

public void drawToScreen()
{
    Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image,0,0,(WIDTH * SCALE), (HEIGHT * SCALE), null);

    g2.dispose();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key){}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key){
    gsm.keyPressed(key.getKeyCode());
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key){
    gsm.keyReleased(key.getKeyCode());
}
}
```

GameState:

```
package GameState;

import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by beuden on 1/3/14.
 */
public abstract class GameState {

    protected GameStateManager gsm;
    public abstract void init();
    public abstract void update();
    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);
    public abstract void keyPressed(int k);
    public abstract void keyReleased(int k);
}


package GameState;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by beuden on 1/3/14.
 */
public class GameStateManager {

private ArrayList<GameState> gameStates;
private int currentState;

public static final int MENUSTATE = 0;
public static final int LEVEL1STATE = 1;

public GameStateManager()
{
    gameStates = new ArrayList<GameState>();

    currentState = MENUSTATE;
    gameStates.add(new MenuState(this));

}

public void setState(int state)
{
    currentState = state;
    gameStates.get(currentState).init();
}

public void update()
{
    gameStates.get(currentState).update();

}

public void draw(Graphics2D g)
{
    gameStates.get(currentState).draw(g);
}

public void keyPressed(int k)
{
    gameStates.get(currentState).keyPressed(k);
}

public void keyReleased(int k)
{
    gameStates.get(currentState).keyReleased(k);
}
}
```

MenuState - This is a single state the game can be in, there will also be a level 1 state.

```
package GameState;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import TileMap.Background;
/**
 * Created by beuden on 1/4/14.
 */
public class MenuState extends GameState {

private Background bg;

private int currentChoice = 0;
private String[] options = {
        "Start",
        "Options",
        "Quit"
};

private Color titleColor;
private Font titleFont;

private Font font;
public MenuState(GameStateManager gsm)
{
    this.gsm = gsm;

    try{
        bg = new Background("/Backgrounds/menubg.gif", 1);
        bg.setVector(-0.1, 0);

        titleColor = new Color(128,0,0);
        titleFont = new Font("Century Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 28);

        font = new Font("Ariel", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}

public void init(){}

public void update(){
    bg.update();
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    //draw background
    bg.draw(g);

    //draw font
    g.setColor(titleColor);
    g.setFont(titleFont);
    g.drawString("Dragon Tale", 80, 70);

    //draw menu options
    g.setFont(font);

    for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
    {
       if(i == currentChoice)
       {
           g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

       }
       else{
           g.setColor(Color.red);
       }
       g.drawString(options[i], 145, 140 + i* 15);
    }

}

public void select()
{
    if(currentChoice == 0)
    {
        //Start
    }
    if(currentChoice == 1)
    {
        //Options
    }
    if(currentChoice == 2)
    {
        //Quit
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
public void keyPressed(int k){
      if(k == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
      {
           select();
      }

      if(k == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
      {
          currentChoice--;
          if(currentChoice < 0)
          {
              currentChoice = options.length - 1;
          }
      }
      if(k == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
      {
          currentChoice++;
          if(currentChoice == options.length)
          {
              currentChoice = 0;
          }
      }
}
public void keyReleased(int k){}

}
```

And Background:

```
package TileMap;

import Main.GamePanel;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

/**
* Created by beuden on 1/4/14.
*/
public class Background {

private BufferedImage image;

private double x, y,dx,dy;

private double moveScale;

public Background(String s, double ms)
{
    try{
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to read image!!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    moveScale = ms;
}

public void setPosition(double x, double y)
{
    this.x = (x * moveScale)%GamePanel.WIDTH;
    this.y = (y * moveScale)%GamePanel.HEIGHT;
}

public void setVector(double dx, double dy)
{
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
}

public void update()
{
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g)
{
    g.drawImage(image, (int)x, (int)y, null);

    if(x < 0){
        g.drawImage(image, (int)x + GamePanel.WIDTH, (int)y, null);
    }
    if(x > 0){
        g.drawImage(image, (int)x - GamePanel.WIDTH, (int)y, null);
    }

}
}
```

The issue occurs in the GamePanel Class.

The Following line:

```
g2.drawImage(image,0,0,(WIDTH * SCALE), (HEIGHT * SCALE), null);
```

causes the crash. Yet change it to:

```
g2.drawImage(image, 0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,null);
```

and the game renders flawlessly, albiet with the measurements above (320,240) making it small but it will draw.

I'm unsure as to why scaling this suddenly causes a crash. Even a simple +1 to any variable causes it to crash.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Just a couple of things to look at/try:  Are you compiling the Java con Windows and running it on Mac?  Are they running the same JVM version? You might try compiling AND running it on the Mac, if you're not already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also run into the same problem calling Graphics.drawImage() on OS/X Mavericks and managed to work around it by manually installing JDK 1.6 and running my code using that instead of 1.7.

See [how-do-i-install-jdk-1-6-in-mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106834/how-do-i-install-jdk-1-6-in-mavericks) for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: This "workaround" assumes the code actually CAN run on 1.6, which most modern Java libraries won't.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue with Maverics not your code.  Part of the Maverics changes where an over haul of the graphics libraries.  And since Apple no longer supports Java it might be a while before Oracle releases an update that has been tested against Maverics.

Since you are using the Java Advanced Imaging lib you might try running it with the headless parameter set to true.  It might by pass the Cocoa graphics libs and use the XWin ones.  That is a long shot.